# iPhone Interface Sizes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

**Where can I get system size of UI elements in iOS?**

For example,

- UIButton corner radius,
- UIWindow size (I know it's 320pt, but is there a constant for it?),
- System font size,
- Navigation bar height,
- Tab bar height,
- Status bar height, etc.

Do they have predefined constants or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UIButton corner radius

I don't think there's an API for that.

> UIWindow size (I know it's 320pt, but is there a constant for it?)

You could get this via `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`.

> System font size

`UIFont` has class methods for getting standard font sizes: `labelFontSize`, `buttonFontSize`, `smallSystemFontSize` and `systemFontSize` are available.

> Navigation bar height,
>   Tab bar height,

The `UIView` instance method `sizeThatFits:` could be used to get the default sizes for those.

> Status bar height

You can get this implicitly by subtracting the height of `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` from `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make a new class with these calculations then.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the common UIElement sizes here: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html